SharePoint Online grouped list JSON formatting
I have a grouped list with 2 columns "Question and "Answer". The list is formatted using the following JSON to format the view. Based on a PNP view formatting sample
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@group.fieldData",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "sp-row-title ms-fontSize-l"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "600px",
        "max-width": "100%",
        "margin": "10px 0"
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalRowClass": "ms-font-l ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary ms-bgColor-white--hover"
}

How can I control the width of the additional row (The Answer Column)? The column contains rich text so I can't format it in the column view.
I've tried adding the following but it made no difference:
"additionalRowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "width": "600px",
      "max-width": "100%"
    }


Multiline text columns with enhanced rich text do not support JSON formatting. Reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/discussions/sharepoint_general/multi-line-text-columns-do-not-support-json-coding/4098651

Dikesh Gandhi's comment is right. Appreciate for his help.
Here I am attaching the official SharePoint documentation which clearly documents the types of JSON formatting columns that are supported and not supported.
Supported column types


Yes I was aware it can't be done in column formatting but I was hoping there may be a way of doing it in view formatting. The additionalRowClass successfully formats the text in the rich text column but I can't get it to change the width.
